# jquery coffeescript live() conversion

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Got caught in a jquery update that got rid of .live(). There are a few posts out there that talk about using on() and it works fine, except for ajax loaded pages.

They then talk about delegating and lost me. I have this simple toggle() coffee script but it is not referencing one element, but many using the data-behavior unobtrusive concept.

```
jQuery ->
  $('[data-behavior="dropdown"]').live( "click", ->
    c = @children[1]
    $(c).toggle())
```

My attempts at delegation by attaching it to the body or container have failed. My coffee-script knowledge is about as bad as my javascript knowledge. I could spend the next day trying to figure this out, or ask for help.

Comment: in Javascript, that's `$(document).on("click", "[data-behavior='dropdown']", function(){...})`

Comment: Thanks. If coffeescript, after a few problem I got `  $(document).on "click", "[data-behavior='dropdown']", ->
    child = this.children[1]
    $(child).toggle()
' to work